# How to scrape time from http://time.is/New_York using PHP?

Tags: php

I don't have any knowledge of PHP but am stuck with scraping time of http://time.is/New_York.

I have used this code:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('http://time.is/New_York');
preg_match('/<div id="twd\d+" [^>]*>([^<]+)<\/div>/im', $contents, $matches);

$title = $matches[0];
print_r($title);
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried any code? We generally request that askers demonstrate some initial attempt, or at least some prior research. Do you have a PHP library in mind?

Comment: I have edited my question above to include the code that I currently came up with.

Comment: And what is the output of that code? What is the output of `print_r($matches);`? A DOM parser (such as DOMDocument) is a better way of parsing HTML, btw - maybe give that a go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://time.is/New_York");
$pattern = '#id="twd">(.*)<#U';

preg_match_all($pattern, $page, $matches); 

echo $matches[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you "scrape" time of other website? You can get date and time in PHP for any timezone:

```php
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('America/New_York'));
echo $dt->format('l, F j, Y, \w\e\e\k W'); # Friday, November 29, 2013, week 48
```

[See the list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) for other timezones available in PHP.

**[Demo](https://eval.in/74372)**

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to come through this website or any other website that fix the ST/DST automatically.

Comment: Does PHP automatically take care of ST/DST?

Comment: @Jahan: ofc, timezones support DST.